# MySQL Query with dynamic Column not working fine with out innerjoin

Tags: mysql, sql

The below query is not running in mysql

```
SELECT (@a:=@a+1 ) AS sl, student_id, student_name, schl_id, class_id  FROM `trans_student` AS TS, **(SELECT @a:=0) bas**  WHERE TS.status= 1 AND `academic_year` = '2016-2017' ORDER BY sl ASC LIMIT 0,15
```

BUT this is running

```
SELECT (@a:=@a+1 ) AS sl, student_id, student_name, schl_id, class_id, academic_year,way, route_name, bus_driver, bus_phone  FROM `trans_student` TS
                 INNER JOIN trans_route TR ON TS.route_id = TR.route_id
                 LEFT JOIN trans_bus TB ON TS.bus_id = TB.bus_id,
                 **(SELECT @a:=0) AS  B**
                 WHERE TS.status= 1 AND `academic_year` = '2016-2017' ORDER BY sl ASC LIMIT 0,15;
```

can you guys help me make the first query running. Some issue with dynamic column as serial number but the 2nd query is working fine with some inner join and left join added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (@a:=@a+1 ) AS sl, student_id, student_name, schl_id, class_id FROM (SELECT @a:=0) as BSS, trans_student AS TS WHERE TS.status= 1 AND academic_year = '2016-2017' ORDER BY sl ASC LIMIT 0,15
```

When put the dynamic table first it worked.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT (@a := @a + 1 ) AS sl, student_id, student_name, schl_id, class_id
FROM `trans_student` TS, 
     (SELECT @a := 0) bas
WHERE TS.status = 1 AND
      `academic_year` = '2016-2017'
ORDER BY sl ASC
LIMIT 0, 15;
```

is fine from what I can tell.  I don't like commas in the `FROM` clause, so I would replace `,` with `CROSS JOIN`.  And, I can't vouch for table names and columns, but the use of variables is fine.

Note that that the `**` should not be in the query.  The error message suggests that those characters are in the query.